# combining two query results into one and using the results to compute another column

Tags: sql

**Query 1 returns one number** AveSpace i.e. 100

```
select avg(spaceusage) as AveSpace
from
(
select top (5) *  from Employee
order by Date desc
) as s
```

**Query 2 returns one number** TotalSpace  i.e. 1000

```
select top(1) TotalSpace from SpaceTable
order by date
```

I want to combines the results into one dataset and add a third column unitSpace that calculates the result from Query 2/ Query 1 i.e 1000/100 =10

**output 3 columns**

```
[AveSpace] [TotalSpace] [unitSpace]

100          1000          10
```

Comment: Do you have a common field between employee and spacetable?

Comment: He won't need a common field, the first query is an aggregate and the second returns TOP 1. So there will never be more than 1 row in each query.

Comment: yes that is correct! i can add a common id to both tables say spaceID

Comment: @KingIsaac, NO, he needs. If there is a common field then all this can be achieved in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat each individual query as a subquery then compute the results:

```
SELECT a.AveSpace, b.TotalSpace, (CAST(a.AveSpace AS float) / CAST(b.TotalSpace AS float)) as UnitSpace
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 AVG(spaceusage) as AveSpace FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Employee ORDER BY date DESC)
    ) a,
    (
         SELECT TOP 1 TotalSpace FROM SpaceTable ORDER BY date
    ) b
```

Comment: many thanks looks fine. However the the result for unitspace i.e 7/4= 1 not 1.75

Comment: My bad, overlooked the integer division. See the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @TotalSpace FLOAT

SELECT TOP 1 @TotalSpace = TotalSpace from SpaceTable
order by date

SELECT select avg(spaceusage) as AveSpace, @TotalSpace AS TotalSpace, @TotalSpace/avg(spaceusage) AS unitSpace
from
(
select top (5) *  from Employee
order by Date desc
) as s